# Char 2D array in map in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, dictionary

How can I use a 2D char array with a map in C++. I want to do this:

```
map<char[50][50],int>M;

char brr[50][50];
//some operation here on the array
int aa=1;

if(M.find(brr)==M.end())
{
     M[brr]=aa;
     aa+=1;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've just found another way. This way I can achieve what I stated in my question. Instead of using the 2d array I'm just gonna convert it into a string and use it. It'll still yield the same result:

```
map<string,int>M;

char brr[50][50];
//some operation here on the array
int aa=1,i,j;

string ss="";

for(i=0;i<50;i++)
{
     for(j=0;j<50;j++)
     {
         ss+=brr[i][j];
     }
}

if(M.find(ss)==M.end())
{
     M[ss]=aa;
     aa+=1;
}
```

Comment: Read further into Oli's answer;  Much of what he says has to do with the underlying container that the STL uses in `map` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B\) ).  It is typically a Red Black Tree.

Comment: Please don't write answers into questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Arrays can't be assigned to (i.e. you can't do `brr = XXX;` in your example), and this is a requirement of the key type of a `std::map`.  Also, the key needs to have a *strict weak ordering* defined on it (i.e. it needs `operator<` or a comparator function).

You could consider wrapping your array in a class, defining an appropriate `operator <`, and then using this as the key type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a wrapper class, and it needs to support `operator<`.  If a lexographical ordering is fine, you can do something like this:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::array<boost::array<char, 50>, 50> Array;

    std::map<Array, int> m;
}
```

`boost::array` can be replaced with `std::array` if you are using C++11.